# Release ExoPlayer in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, exoplayer

I am implementing the ExoPlayer in a RecyclerView. But while scrolling the Video stops, but not the audio.

How can I release the ExoPlayer in the RecyclerView? Or how can I get the position of the Recycled Object so I am able to release the ExoPlayer?

This is my Data Object

```
public class            enter code here           Video {
    private String url;
    private Context context;
    Boolean playWhenReady = false;
    int currentWindow = 0;
    long playbackPosition = 0;
    ExoPlayer player;

    public Video(String url, Context context) {
        this.url = url;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setCurrentWindow(int currentWindow) {
        this.currentWindow = currentWindow;
    }

    public void setPlaybackPosition(long playbackPosition) {
        this.playbackPosition = playbackPosition;
    }

    public void setPlayWhenReady(Boolean playWhenReady) {
        this.playWhenReady = playWhenReady;
    }

    public void setPlayer(ExoPlayer player) {
        this.player = player;
    }

    public ExoPlayer getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public Boolean getPlayWhenReady() {
        return playWhenReady;
    }

    public int getCurrentWindow() {
        return currentWindow;
    }

    public long getPlaybackPosition() {
        return playbackPosition;
    }
}
```

And this my Adapter Class:
I tried it with the onViewRecycled() Method, but because I dont get the position i can´t release the player.

```
public class VideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Video> mDataset;


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public PlayerView mExoPlayer;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mExoPlayer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        }
    }

    public VideoAdapter(ArrayList<Video> myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {


        initPlayer(holder,position);

    }

    private void initPlayer(ViewHolder holder,int position) {
        mDataset.get(position).setPlayer(ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
                new DefaultRenderersFactory(mDataset.get(position).getContext()),
                new DefaultTrackSelector(), new DefaultLoadControl()));

        holder.mExoPlayer.setPlayer(mDataset.get(position).getPlayer());

        mDataset.get(position).getPlayer().setPlayWhenReady(mDataset.get(position).getPlayWhenReady());
        mDataset.get(position).getPlayer().seekTo(mDataset.get(position).getCurrentWindow(), mDataset.get(position).getPlaybackPosition());

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(mDataset.get(position).getUrl());
        MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri);
        mDataset.get(position).getPlayer().prepare(mediaSource, true, false);
    }

    private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {

        return new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(
                new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer-codelab")).
                createMediaSource(uri);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    }


}
```

Comment: Can u please share complete code how can i use exo player in recycler view.

Comment: I made a new project that can help everyone that is trying do it: https://github.com/paulo-coutinho/rvplayer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that it would be cleanest to release the player when its view is recycled.

**Adapter Class:**

```
@Override
public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull ViewHolder holder) {
    int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
    if (mDataset.get(position) != null) {
        mDataset.get(position).getPlayer().release();
    }
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
}
```

Comment: If you `release()` the player it cannot be used again so this isn't a good idea if you plan to reuse the player in the recycled view.

Comment: @ChristopherPerry How to then release the player and reinstantiate it?

Comment: @Arjun You should store a single instance of the player in the parent Activity/Fragment, instantiating the player inside the `onResume()` method and releasing the player inside the `onStop()` method. [Here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/76962d50f1d80941d6768e4e765fa4ff010705e7/demos/cast) is an official demo that implements this. It has a bunch of other stuff going on but specifically look at MainActivity.java and PlayerManager.java.

Comment: Also, Christopher Perry was correct when they stated that [the player cannot be used after release](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/Player.html#release--).

Comment: what is the FilePath ?

Answer (score 4):

```
  holder.yourplayername.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {
                holder.yourplayername.getPlayer().stop();

            }
        });
```

hi.i hope this code helpful for you becuse work for me.

Comment: it stop video but if your video on half screen it still playing after stop video on screen again want to play it show blank?what is this solution of this

Comment: @Adnanhaider This is not a correct solution. You never want to release your ExoPlayer if one of its `view`s has been detached from window.

Answer (score 0):

The system cannot hold multiple `ExoPlayer` instances. It can throw an `OOM Exception`. Therefore, you must release `ExoPlayer` when the user does not see the item. In this case, I suggest you use the bellow method from `RecyclerView.Adapter`

```
override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder: ViewHolder) {
    holder.itemView.player?.stop()
    holder.itemView.player?.release()
    holder.itemView.player = null
    super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder)
}
```

And then, in `ViewHolde`r class you should check, if `player == null`, you must initialize it.

Comment: Having a new instance for every holder is not very performant. It is mentioned in the ExoPlayer's GitHub issues page