# Exoplayer in recyclerView gives out of memory exception

Tags: android-recyclerview, video-streaming, out-of-memory, exoplayer2.x

RecyclerView with each item as an **Exoplayer throws out of memory exception even after releasing the player in onViewRecycled()** method of adapter.
what i can do to resolve this issue?

i have gone through other posts about this issue, out of that i tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51686098/release-exoplayer-in-recyclerview) but this also is not working.

And i have **already increased the heapSize in manifest**.

snippet of code from adapter:

```
     override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MemoryHomeHolder, position:Int) 
     {
        val memory = memoryList[position]
        holder.bind(memory)
        holder.itemMemoryListBinding.playerView?.useController = true
        holder.itemMemoryListBinding.playerView?.showController()

        val path: memory.path

        val player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
            context,
            DefaultTrackSelector(),
            DefaultLoadControl()
        )
        val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(
            context,
            Util.getUserAgent(context, AppConstants.OFH)
        )
        val source = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory) .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(path))
        holder.itemMemoryListBinding.playerView?.player = player

        holder.itemMemoryListBinding.playerView?.controllerHideOnTouch = false
        holder.itemMemoryListBinding.playerView?.controllerShowTimeoutMs = -1
        holder.itemMemoryListBinding.playerView?.resizeMode =
        AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL
        holder.itemMemoryListBinding.playerView?.exo_progress?.visibility 
        = View.GONE
        (holder.itemMemoryListBinding.playerView?.player as 
         SimpleExoPlayer?)?.prepare(source)
        (holder.itemMemoryListBinding.playerView?.player as 
        SimpleExoPlayer?)?.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL

        activePlayerHolders.add(holder)
        Log.d(TAG, "holder init for position = $position")
   }

   override fun onViewRecycled(holder: MemoryHomeHolder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder)
        holder.itemMemoryListBinding.playerView?.player?.release()
   }
```

I want the RecyclerView to have Exoplayer as an item in every holder and it should not throw out of memory exception

Answer (score 1):

I was not releasing the player properly on **onViewRecycled()** method, which created out of memory exception.

you can simply release the player of the holder being released as below:

```
holder?.playerView?.player?.release()
```

This fixed the issue.