# Failed to initialize OMX.MTK.VIDEO.DECODER.AVC, error 0xfffffff4

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-storage

I'm trying to load videos from firebase storage to my recycler view with **ExoPlayer**. But the problem is that the video sometimes does not play and if i hit the play button it gives me this error below

```
Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.MTK.VIDEO.DECODER.AVC......
```

I tried calling the `release()` method after/before setting the player to the player view but nothing changed.

I have wasted over 5 days to fix this problem and i can't find any solution for it.

There is any **ExoPlayer** alternative to load videos from firebase to recycler view?

**Part of code from onBindViewHolder inside my Recycler Adpater:**

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

            ExoPlayer player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
            MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(postList.get(position).getImgUrl());
            player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
            player.prepare();
            videoViewHolder.andExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
    }
```

**And i'm initializing the playerView inside view holder like this:**

```
public VideoViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        andExoPlayerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.andExoPlayerView);
        ........
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Release ExoPlayer in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51686098/release-exoplayer-in-recyclerview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to release the player when the recycler view item are recycled

I find the answer from this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51686755/15477915)

```
@Override
public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull ViewHolder holder) {
    int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
    if (mDataset.get(position) != null) {
        mDataset.get(position).getPlayer().release();
    }
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
}
```

Comment: holder.getAdapterPosition() is Deprecated now you can use bindingAdapterPosition